# Apache2 on Ubuntu port based virtual hosts: Unwanted redirection to wrong port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redirect, apache2, virtualhost

I am running Apache on my local machine (Ubuntu 14.04) in virtual host mode using port based approach. While some virtual hosts work fine, some virtual host calls from a web browser strangely get redirected to a certain port which is not the one that's in the configs.

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```html
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82
Listen 83
Listen 84
Listen 85
Listen 88
Listen 1080

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Example /etc/apache2/sites-available/somesite.conf**

```html
<VirtualHost *:83>
 ServerName localhost

 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /home/me/www/thiswebsite.com
 
 <Directory /home/me/www/thiswebsite.com>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
 # error, crit, alert, emerg.
 # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
 # modules, e.g.
 #LogLevel info ssl:warn

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

While

```
    http://localhost:80 ... http://localhost:83
```

work just as intended, some ports above port 83 get redirected to that port 83: That means, if I call `http://localhost:85` the browser automatically redirects to `http://localhost:83` and connects to the wrong webroot. this also applies to `http://localhost:86` or `http://localhost:87` and so forth. All local webroots have been enabled by #>a2ensite thiswebsite.com.conf ...

What could be a reason for that behaviour and how can I fix this? Your help is much appreciated. Best
Bunjip

Comment: What's the source of your redirects?  And do the ones that fail have virtualhosts defined / what are their contents?

Comment: @covener I'm not quite sure, if I understood what you meant with 'What's the source of redirects'. IMHO the source is Apache webserver.
Yes, the ones that fail have virtual hosts defined. Again, I'm not sure what you mean with 'what are their contents'. If you refer to their virtual host configs then their configs look similiar to the one above but customized to each port, server name and webroot.